# Android app layout not updated unless I restart eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, restart, adt

Im Very new to android development.
Im following this guide: http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#overview
for some reason, any change in my application is not reflected unless i restart eclipse.
It doesnt matter if i uninstall the app using ADB, the emulator itselt.
I clicked "refresh" and run numerous times but not avail.
I completely changed the layout everytime but I had to restart eclipse itself (not the adt) in order for it to reflect changes.
Am I missing something here? thanks.

Eclipse 3.6.2 on Windows7 64bit

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuild your project?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project name in Eclipse, select Run As.., Android Application. Then you should see a pop up window showing the running Emulators. Select one from the list, and click Ok.

Also make sure your app doesn't have any compile errors, as that could definitley screw things up.

After trying to run, check the Eclipse console and it should say "Uploading yourapp.apk to Device..." or something. And it should launch the app on the Emulator. Look for any errors in the Console as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and worked around by changing or removing android:id attribute of a root element (typically viewgroup).  I have Eclipse SDK 3.7.0 running Win7 64bit

Hope this helps